# when i run my server in django i get this request error , i've been using bootstrap

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, bootstrap-modal

when running the server (`python manage.py runserver`)and asking for a request in my view i get this error 
 Not Found: /assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
[13/Dec/2015 14:09:25] "GET /assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2264

this is my view :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import EmailForm
def home(request):
    print request
    form = EmailForm()
    context = {"form": form}
    template = "home.html"
    return render(request, template, context)
```

this is the end of my html file that was pulled from bootstrap.
this is the page i took the elements from (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/):

```
 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That script is a [workaround for a bug in IE10](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width). The url `../../assets/...` is a relative url that works on the bootstrap site. You can't just copy and paste it to another page and expect it to work.

You'll need to create a new static file that contains the required javascript, or add it to an existing file / script tag.

Comment: i did pull the url from the site which is (http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js) and it still didnt work for me , do you have any idea why , sorry for misdirecting you

Comment: Changing the url to `/assets` it won't work unless a) you create that file on your server and b) you configure your server to server that file. With Django, it would be better to add the file to your static files, then serve it from there e.g. `/static/assets/...`.

Comment: Thanks ! , i've looked up a video of managing your static files and with your help i was able to save the scripts and redirect bootstrap to the right directory. thank you very much for helping me with the error :)

Answer (score 0):

This is what solved the problem for me. If you are using Chrome:

Open DevTools (Ctrl + Shift + J) -> Settings (F1) -> Disable cache (while DevTools is open).